# Creating a data packet for UDP in Simulink

Tags: udp, simulink

I'm trying to create and send a packet of data in Simulink using the UDP Send block. The receiver is a Labview executable addressed via local port. I have the addressing down correctly, so I can see that I'm sending data, but I'm having trouble packaging the data since I'm new to Simulink and UDP.

What I want to do is package and send 256 bytes of data, where bytes 1-10ish are specified but the remaining bytes are spare. I was able to accomplish this by creating a 1x256 vector in an embedded Matlab function and addressing the fields within the function, but I've been asked to accomplish this task using only Simulink, with no Matlab. I've tried using the Mux block with 256 inputs, leaving ~245 inputs unconnected and connecting the inputs I care about, but I'm not getting the correct values sent. What is the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [MATLAB Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block, with code something like

```
function y = create_test_data()

y = zeros(256,1);
y(1:10,1) = rand(10,1);
```

Then feed the output into an appropriately configured [UDP Send](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/udpsend.html) block.

(This approach would be considered `only Simulink`.)